# Using Python to Generate a List of Filenames Within Code

Tags: python, list

I'd like to use a Python script to create a list of song files from a folder sorted by author then by song title. I worked on making this with a friend who is proficient in Python, unlike myself.

Only need this for a single purpose, likely won't be using Python again. Any help, or just outwrite creating a script that'd work would be much appreciated.

My Script:

```
import os

path = r"C:\Users\***\Desktop\New folder"

os.chdir(path)

file1 = open("myfile.txt", "a")  # append mode

print(os.listdir())
files = glob.glob("*.ogg")
print(files)

import bisect

files_sorted = []
authorsDict = {}
# add files into authorsDict
for filename in files:
    formattedName = filename[:-4].split(" by ")
    if formattedName[1] not in authorsDict:
        authorsDict[formattedName[1]] = [filename]
    else:
        bisect.insort(authorsDict[formattedName[1]], filename)

# find the sorted order of keys in authorsDict
sortedKeys = sorted(authorsDict.keys())

# combine the lists in authorsDict in order
for key in sortedKeys:
    files_sorted = files_sorted + authorsDict[key]

for filename in files_sorted:
     filenamestorage = filename[:-4]
     if filename.endswith(".ogg"):
        file1.write("music = {\n")
        file1.write(" " + "name =" + '"' + filenamestorage + '"\n')
        file1.write(" " + "file = " + '"' + filename + '"\n')
        file1.write("volume = 1.00\n")
        file1.write("}\n")
        file1.write("\n")
        file1.close()
     else:
        continue
```

How I'd like the output in myfile.txt to look like:

````
    name = "Jesus bleibet meine Freude by Bach"
    file = "Jesus bleibet meine Freude by Bach.ogg"
    volume = 1.00
}
music = {
    name = "Missa No. 1 1st Movement 'Kyrie Eleison' by Bach"
    file = "Missa No. 1 1st Movement 'Kyrie Eleison' by Bach.ogg"
    volume = 1.00
}
music = {
    name = "Partita No. 2 5th Movement Chaconne by Bach"
    file = "Partita No. 2 5th Movement Chaconne by Bach.ogg"
    volume = 1.00
}
music = {
    name = "St. Johns Passion, Ruht Wohl by Bach"
    file = "St. Johns Passion, Ruht Wohl by Bach.ogg"
    volume = 1.00
}
music = {
    name = "Toccata and Fugue by Bach"
    file = "Toccata and Fugue by Bach.ogg"
    volume = 1.00
}
music = {
    name = "Concerto for Orchestra 1st Movement by Bartók"
    file = "Concerto for Orchestra 1st Movement by Bartók.ogg"
    volume = 1.00
}```
````

Comment: Can you please describe what is the current error/bug you are facing?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: The response is just wrong;
```['.py', 'Aria Dochiței (Crai Nou) by Porumbescu.ogg', 'Battlefield 1942 Intro by Livingstone.ogg', 'Humoresque No. 7 In G Flat Major Op. 101 by Dvořák.ogg', 'myfile.txt', "Pictures at an Exhibition_ XIV. No 9, The Hut on Fowl's Legs by Ravel.mp3", 'Symphony No 2 October by Shostakovich.mp3']
['Aria Dochiței (Crai Nou) by Porumbescu.ogg', 'Battlefield 1942 Intro by Livingstone.mp3', 'Humoresque No. 7 In G Flat Major Op. 101 by Dvořák.mp3', "Pictures at an Exhibition_ XIV. No 9, The Hut on Fowl's Legs by Ravel.ogg", 'Symphony No 2 October by Shostakovich.ogg']```

Comment: There isn't a given error, I think, but it's not doing what I want it to, like above.